# How to get ssh public keys of a Jenkins master in a docker container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-docker

We followed Jenkins's official guide and our master is running as a docker container. I'm now trying to set up another machine as slave for this Jenkins master and I think I need to manually copy the public SSH keys of the master to the new slave machine. How do I access these keys? Isn't it a problem that the Jenkins container that can be destroyed and created many times? It does have a persistent volume container for jenkins data but I'm assuming that's not where the keys are.